# How to add a tab in product details page using Magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento-2.1, tabs, product-page

how to add a tab in product details page using Magento 2 admin panel. Is there any option to do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the below given step

1-Go to `store->product->Add New Attribute`

2- Set **default label** for your custom tab and **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner**

```
for ex:-Text Area
```

3- Set **Attribute code** and **scope** under **Advanced Attribute Properties** and save it

```
for ex:- custom_tab or customtab (Attribute code)
For ex:- Global (scope)
```

4- Now go to `Store->Attribute Set->default` and you can see your attribute under **Unassigned Attribute**. Drag your attribute under **Content group**  and save

5- Go to `app\design\frontend\Custom-theme-folder\theme-folder\Magento_Catalog\layout` and create if not exist `catalog_product_view.xml` and paste the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">            
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="custom.tab" template="product/view/view.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Care</argument>
                </arguments>            
             </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

6- Now go to `\app\design\frontend\your-theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view` and create view.phtml and write the following code

```
<?php
$product=$block->getProduct();
?>
<h1><?php echo $product->getData('custom_tab');?></h1>
```

And i created my custom tab successfully. and i hope this will also help other peoples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something that Magento also does, it's always best to look at **how** Magento does this itself. If you look at `Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` you'll see something like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</block>
```

So if you want to add a tab in your own theme our module, my best guess would be to create a file called `catalog_product_view.xml` and add it to the `product.info.details`-block. This example would add the value of `my_attribute`:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.my_attribute" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getMyAttribute</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">my_attribute</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">my_attribute</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">My Attribute</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</block>
```

Ofcourse, instead of `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description` you can use your own custom block class and template, just as long as you keep the `group="detailed_info"` in your layout XML (this is what adds the tab to the template).

Haven't tried this example yet, but it should work (or at least point you in the right direction).