# Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract

Tags: magento2, layout, theme

I flow [How to add a tab in product details page using Magento 2 admin panel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223417/how-to-add-a-tab-in-product-details-page-using-magento-2-admin-panel) step to add a custom tab

**and I got this error**
[image]

**my file struct**
[image]

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="custom.tab" template="product/view/view.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Care</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view.phtml**

```
<?php
$product=$block->getProduct();
?>
<h1><?php echo $product->getData('custom_tab');?></h1>
```

**How Can I solve this error**

Answer (score 0):

Try to change  attribute from string to text

```
<argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="text">Care</argument>
```